# Appending a Dictionary Value that is a Tuple in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to make a python dictionary that takes user input, splits it into a list of two indices, takes the second index as the dictionary key and the first as the dictionary value - but cast as a Tuple. Hope that makes sense! I have it working, but when I enter another input with the same key, I want the new value appended to the tuple already in the dictionary. I get that tuples are immutable and there is no append (or so I think) so what magic do I need to sprinkle to get it to add to the tuple in the dictionary?

My code so far is:

```
desserts = {}

name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

while name_vote != '':
  no_colon_name_vote = name_vote.replace(":", " ")
  name, vote = no_colon_name_vote.split()
  name = tuple([name])
  if vote not in desserts:
    desserts[vote] = name
  else:
    desserts[vote].append(name)   #this is where I'm hitting a brick wall
  name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

print(desserts)
```

And my desired output from two inputs should be

```
Name:vote Luke:icecream
Name:vote Bob:icecream
Name:vote 
{'icecream': ('Luke', 'Bob')}
```

Comment: If you need an ordered mutable collection of elements, I suggest using a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: You should be careful of how you `split`, because if someone enters a name like `Bill Clinton: Yes`, then you're code will throw an error

Comment: Fair points on both comments, but the activity follows a load of instructions about how tuples can be used as values ... and it stipulates that names will only be entered as forenames

Comment: You can't append to a tuple because it is immutable but if you are really set on using a tuple instead of a list you can do `deserts[vote] += name`

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have it!

```
desserts = {}

name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

while name_vote != '':
  no_colon_name_vote = name_vote.replace(":", " ")
  name, vote = no_colon_name_vote.split()
  name = tuple([name])
  if vote not in desserts:
    desserts[vote] = name
  else:
    original = desserts[vote]
    desserts[vote] = (original + name)
  name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')

print(desserts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `list` to store values and `defaultdict` will be a lot easier, if you are going to be adding names all the time using a mutable container would make more sense:

```
from collections import defaultdict
desserts = defaultdict(list)
name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')
while name_vote != '':
    no_colon_name_vote = name_vote.replace(":", " ")
    name, vote = no_colon_name_vote.split()
    desserts[vote].append(name)  
    name_vote = input ('Name:vote ')
print(desserts)
```

If you want tuples you can cast the lists to tuple after:

```
for k,v in desserts.iteritems():
    desserts[k] = tuple(v)
```